# How to populate dataset using SqlDataReader while stored procedure returns multiple tables?

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp.net-ajax, c#-3.0

I am executing a stored procedure in asynchronous mode from codebehind using `SqlCommand`'s `BeginExecuteNonQuery` or `BeginExecuteReader` method.

The stored procedure returns multiple tables as there are more than 1 select statement.

I want to get those tables in a DataSet.

Is it possible?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a SqlDataAdapter to fill the dataset like this:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("exec spSomeStoredProc", conn);
adapter.Fill(dataset);

// dataset.Tables[0] - refers to resultset obtained from first SQL query 
// in stored procedure. dataset.Tables[1] - refers to resultset obtained
// from second SQL query. Etc.
```

If it has to be done Async take a look at the code in the following article which shows how to pull back a DataSet asynchronously.

[Asynchronous DataSet](http://www.williablog.net/williablog/post/2007/12/19/Asynchronous-DataSet.aspx)